# Distribution .dist-id

Tags: raku

EDIT: Updated the question because I was confusing `.dist-id` with `.id`;

I'm trying to uninstall  dist, but when I pass the `Distribution` to `.uninstall` it looks like it calculates different `.dist-id` and the `Distribution` does not get uninstalled.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku

my $dist = $*REPO.candidates( 'Grid' ).head;
say $dist.WHAT, $dist.Str, $dist.dist-id;

say $*REPO.uninstall( $dist );
say $*REPO.uninstall( $dist ); # still there

# OUTPUT:
(LazyDistribution)Grid:ver<0.0.2>:auth<>:api<0>ADCD0F3EFF816F1212D5513F201B8143E2BDD6FF
["/home/hythm/.perl6/dist/157B7E1F2BB827C99A5EF3241D61853A85E57734".IO] # shouldn't this hash be the one above ↑ ?
["/home/hythm/.perl6/dist/157B7E1F2BB827C99A5EF3241D61853A85E57734".IO]
```

Answer (score 5):

I can almost guarantee it is being uninstalled. Your assumption that `uninstall` returning some path means it didn't work is incorrect. See: `raku -e 'unlink("asdfaefawfk")'`, try adding a `require ::("XXX")` between the `uninstall`s, or try running your example two different times.

`.dist-id` is not used for the directory -- this is easily verified by looking at the source for `uninstall` -- https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/57f4a4c933e5f9c896051793722b33f254786695/src/core.c/CompUnit/Repository/Installation.pm6#L334

You are also using `$*REPO` incorrectly. You almost always need to grep `$*REPO.repo-chain` for the specific repository you require; don't assume the first repository is always what you think it is (because it suddenly isn't when you do e.g. `-I lib`)

Comment: May be it is not "fully" uninstalled? Here is what I'm doing.

1- install `Grid` by `zef` to `home` repository.

2- `zef` installed for files into the repo, one file under dist, one file under sources, a directory under short, and a file under.

3- running the above script, I see only one file get uninstalled, (the file under sources). the dist file which is under "dist" is still there.

4- Try to install `Grid` again, with `Zef` says already installed, (meaning it was not installed).

note: uninstalling via zef works fine though and removes all 4 files.

Comment: Install zef to home directory. Then run `$ perl6 -e 'my $dist = $*REPO.candidates("Zef").head; say $*REPO.uninstall($dist); require ::("Zef"); say $*REPO.uninstall($dist)'`. Note how it will tell you it could not find zef.

Comment: I did not geta `require` error, here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/hythm7/793ccd7c9d225a02bd691448bcee779d

Comment: I think I did not get the error because `require` will look for `Zef` int he repo-chain and eventually will find it in `site` repo.

Comment: Yes, if you have multiple copies of zef installed then the example will not hold. Don't do that.

Comment: I'm accepting this because `.uninstall` works fine. proved by `require` above. I most likely have a different issue, related to the way I install a `Distribution`  (bypassing Zef).